# Collision Detection / Translation error

Tags: opengl, translation

When my sprite collides with another shape, my sprite disappears and is redrawn at its original x/y position and I'm unsure why?

Can anyone suggest an alteration to my code to stop the sprite disappearing but instead to stay where it was before the initial collision?

I've tried reversing the `glTranslation` and also tried setting the values to `0` in the `move()` function to stop it moving but I have been unsuccessful.

```
void move(){

    if(check_collision(sprite,platform1) || check_collision(sprite,platform2)){ //if colliding
        //x_Vel = 0; y_Vel = 0;
    }
    else{ //if not colliding
        glTranslatef(x_Vel, y_Vel, 0.0);
    }
}

void drawSprite (RECT rect) { ... }
```

Comment: Beware that your collision detection will fail if your velocity gets large enough that the boxes are passing through each other in 1 tic.  In that case, you'll need a better system that checks if the box you swept passes through the other box.  It's not hard, a littel vector math, but it is something you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got yourself a bit tied in knots here, possibly not helped by your choice of variable names.

`x_Vel` and `y_Vel` appear to actually be the position, rather than a velocity. When you feed these to `glTranslate()` it simply adds that translation to the current transform. In your case it's just changing where on screen your object is drawn. If your object collides, you're not translating at all, so of course things are drawn in a different place.

Obviously setting the position to zero will also not work, neither will negating it.

What you need to do, is leave `glTranslate()` alone, and instead not allow movement in a given direction when objects collide. This should happen when you update the positions. You are trying to handle the collision inside the display function, which is not going to work - you've already moved the object at this point, GL cannot help you.

So, not that I'd recommend using `OpenGL` like this in the first place (this functionality is deprecated, and inefficient), but if you are going to use `glTranslate()` etc., realise that it does nothing more than control how things are drawn - it does not handle *movement*. That is your responsibility.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes more sense, thanks for explaining it. 
How would you recommend handling movement? `glTranslation` is the only way I can think of moving the sprite from keyboard input, hence why I'm trying to handle collision with it too.

Comment: glTranslate will display your sprite in any position you want. It is up to you to calculate the correct position, including inputs and collision.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm struggling unfortunately.

Comment: You need to do the collision detection when you move the sprite, not when you draw it. i.e. when you udpate `x_Vel` and `y_Vel`. The simplest method, though certainly not the most accurate, would be to check the new position for a collision before moving. If it collides, don't move at all.